# How to get a process' memory and time usage?

Tags: c++, memory-management, process, ptrace, readprocessmemory

I'm trying to get a process's memory and time usage,and here is [[my code]](https://git.oschina.net/jialin/Curious)
but the memory reported is so much for such a simple app consuming almost 8500Kb. Has something I've done reported the wrong memory usage or are there other reasons?

```
#include "trace.h"
#include "include.h"
#include "trace.cpp"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    trace t;
    t.SetLimitInfo();
    t.CreateProcess();
    t.waitForChild();


    cout<<"time usage: "<<t.getTime()<<"ms memory usage: "<<t.GetMemory()<<"kb"<<endl;
    // insert code here...
//    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `valgrind --tool=massif` to check memory usage.

Check [the doc](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)